# twitter bootstrap with oracle apex

Tags: oracle, twitter-bootstrap, oracle-apex

Has anyone successfully integrated an oracle apex application with twitter bootstrap? Is there anything special in order for everything to be referenced correctly such as my css and javascript?

Comment: @angabriel You are on a `boostrap` to `bootstrap` correction spree? Too many edits in last few minutes :)

Comment: sorry m8 I was not aware this triggers a live person. I will be more careful now ;). Thank you for notifying me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap in one of my internal Applications. Did work quite well, no special things to do, just standard includes of the required files.

Comment: is there anything special you need to do in order to get it to work with the less framework? How did you include your files? Did you upload them to the images and references them that way? Thanks!